# ¿Cómo transmitir un archivo en GNU Radio? Proyecto de cifrado de comunicaciones por Radio Definida por Software

Tags: python, radio, cifrado

### **Hola Comunidad, Feliz día!!**

Les agradezco si alguno de ustedes ha trabajado con **GNU RADIO**, para la transmisión y recepción de archivos, necesito enviar un archivo binario identico en la Fuente al Destino.

He estado trabajando con dos flowgrapghs, un Transmisor FM previamente configurado, con conocimientos parciales en el tema, e igualmente en el receptor. Resulta que al enviar el archivo .wav, llega con exito al Receptor con algo de ruido que es normal en las comunicaciones, sin embargo, el archivo que llega no es nada igual a pesar de que se escuche el audio.

Transmisor:

[image: Transmisor]

Receptor:

[image: Receptor]

Lo que necesito en verdad, es llevar un archivo binario y mandarlo exatamente igual al receptor, puesto que en este proyecto, estoy cifrando unas comunicaciones por radio y uso la librería pycryptodome, entonces al enviar el binario encriptado al destino no me llega exactamente igual por lo cual el archivo recibido no es interpretado por el código de descifrado que automáticamente me entrega Error.

Estos son los códigos de cifrado y descifrado, ya las llaves fueron autómaticamente generadas con otro cript.

Código para generar llaves:

```
from Crypto.PublicKey import RSA

key = RSA.generate(2048)         #Genera una llave privada
private_key = key.export_key()
file_out = open("private.pem", "wb")
file_out.write(private_key)
file_out.close()

public_key = key.publickey().export_key() #Genera una llave pública
print(public_key)
file_out = open("receiver.pem", "wb")
file_out.write(public_key)
file_out.close()
```

Código para encriptar:

```
from Crypto.PublicKey import RSA
from Crypto.Random import get_random_bytes
from Crypto.Cipher import AES, PKCS1_OAEP

#data = open("sample_1.bin", "rb")
data = open("archivo.wav", "rb")
datos = data.read()
print(data)
file_out = open("encrypted_data.bin", "wb") #Exporta un archivo ¿encriptado?

recipient_key = RSA.import_key(open("receiver.pem").read()) #Importa una llave del archivo receiver.pem
session_key = get_random_bytes(16) #Genera una llave para la sesión cipher_aes 16 ¿bytes?

# Encrypt the session key with the public RSA key
cipher_rsa = PKCS1_OAEP.new(recipient_key) #Crea un objeto para cifrar con "recipient_key" 
enc_session_key = cipher_rsa.encrypt(session_key) #Encripta session key

# Encrypt the data with the AES session key
cipher_aes = AES.new(session_key, AES.MODE_EAX) #Crea un objeto para el cifrado simétrico con la llave pública
ciphertext, tag = cipher_aes.encrypt_and_digest(datos) #Cifra la información
[ file_out.write(x) for x in (enc_session_key, cipher_aes.nonce, tag, ciphertext) ] #exporta un archivo binario
file_out.close()
data.close()
```

Archivo de desencripción:

```
from Crypto.PublicKey import RSA
from Crypto.Cipher import AES, PKCS1_OAEP

while True:
   try:
      file_in = open("encrypted_data.bin", "rb")
      file_out = open("sample_2.bin", "wb")

      private_key = RSA.import_key(open("private.pem").read()) #Importa la llave privada

      enc_session_key, nonce, tag, ciphertext = \
         [ file_in.read(x) for x in (private_key.size_in_bytes(), 16, 16, -1) ] # importa la llave AES, texto cifrado y otros parámetros

      # Decrypt the session key with the private RSA key
      cipher_rsa = PKCS1_OAEP.new(private_key) #crea un objeto con el cuqal descifra con la llave privada
      session_key = cipher_rsa.decrypt(enc_session_key) #desencripta la llave AES

      # Decrypt the data with the AES session key
      cipher_aes = AES.new(session_key, AES.MODE_EAX, nonce) #crea el objeto para descifrar
      data = cipher_aes.decrypt_and_verify(ciphertext, tag) #Descifra
      #print(data.decode("utf-8")) #Imprime texto descifrado
      file_out.write(data)
      file_out.close()
      break

   except:
      print("Error!!")
```

A este último script le añado un try exception para poder examinar un poco más el archivo cifrado que llega pero creo que no me sirve de nada.

Desearía trabajar con modulación digital haber si mejora la recepción. Quiero tratar con estos flowgraphs que conseguí en Internet, pero la versión GNU Radio ya es antigua y no existen ciertos bloque como el *Packet Encoder*.

Transmisor:

[image: Transmisor digital]

Receptor:

[image: Receptor digital]

Estoy trabajando con una USRP N210 como transmisor, y un RTL-SDR RTL2832U en el receptor.

Estoy trabajando con GNURadio v3.8.0.57

Muchas gracias.

[image: USRP N210 - Equipo de Transmisión]
[image: RTL2832U - Equipo de Recepción]

Comment: Hola! Bienvenidx a SOes. 
Las preguntas del tipo "Tengo que hacer esto y no se por donde empezar" no suelen ser bien recibidas, ya que la respuesta será siempre muy amplia y no encaja en el formato del sitio.
Recomiendo que hagas el [recorrido](https://es.stackoverflow.com/tour) para entender el sitio y de paso ganar tu primera medalla. 
También estaría bien que revisaras [Cómo preguntar](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) para que recibas respuesta cuanto antes.

Comment: Recuerda que puedes [edit] tu pregunta cuantas veces sea necesario (incluso si termina cerrada) y añadir la info relevante a forma de [Ejemplo mínimo](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) (en los comentarios no se ve bien el código y abajo sólo van nuestros intentos de respuesta). Una buena pregunta siempre termina reabierta :)